# SQL joins with Like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have tables like these

tableUser:

```
id   | name
-----+------------
1    | John Smith
2    | Maria
3    | peter
```

tableComplaint

```
id   | ComplaintIssue   | User
-----+------------------+-----
1    | Isssue1          |  1
2    | Issue nth        |  3
3    | Issue infinity   |  4
```

Now I'm trying to get output from below query

```
select 
    tc.id, tc.complaintissue, tu.name tc 
from 
    tablecomplaint tc
join 
    tbuser tu on tu.id = tc.user
where 
    tc.comlaintissue like '%%' or tu.name like '%%'
```

but I'm not able to put like operator on `tu.name`.

I want my output query allowed to search with user's name also.

Comment: Your sql looks fine to me (other than a spelling error in the word complaint in the where clause). What isn't working?

Comment: What is the datatype of `name`? Some types cannot be used with the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: What does this mean:  "I'm not able to put like operator on tu.name"?

Comment: `tc.name tc from tablecomplaint tc` is wrong, as is `where tc.comlaintissue`. Read the SQL you're writing, and the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

you have "tc" appearing twice

```
select tc.id, tc.complaintissue, tu.name [->]tc from tablecomplaint [->] tc
join tbuser tu on tu.id = tc.user
where tc.comlaintissue like '%%' or tu.name like '%%'
```

you tried to mean?

```
select tc.id, tc.complaintissue, tu.name from tablecomplaint tc
join tbuser tu on tu.id = tc.user
where tc.comlaintissue like '%%' or tu.name like '%%'
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked,

```
select 
    tc.id, tc.complaintissue, tu.name tc 
from 
    tablecomplaint tc
join 
    tbuser tu on tu.id = tc.user
where 
    tc.complaintissue like '%%' or tu.name like '%%'
```